# How to get wordpress password using hash and salt key?

Tags: wordpress, passwords, salt

I forgot my wordpress admin password but i am able to get into my DB and have the hashed password and also i have salt key from my wp-config.php file.

Does anyone know how can i get my password back from above details.

I tried doing forgot password thing but i never got email to reset password.

Comment: If you are bale to get in DB try to update password from there by set type MD5 in password field.

Comment: how do i set field type to MD5 in mysql

Comment: Read here to make your one. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/wordpress-password-hash-generator/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Open `localhost/phpmyadmin`
- Open the database then table `wp_users`
- Edit the corresponding row of user
- Copy and keep the old password (for backup)
- Edit field `user_pass' and type value
- Change Type to `MD5` and then update the row.

Comment: This solution will make the new password.
Keyur has asked about getting the old password back not for new password...

Answer (score 4):

You can reset your password using database password field.
goto your database users table.
find password field. It can be seen as hash.
Generate new hash using this generator, http://www.danstools.com/md5-hash-generator/
replace new hash.

Answer (score 0):

Input a new password and generate its hash.

Then update password column in the user table through MySQL database with the new generated hash.

After that you can log in to the backend using the new password.